# How to search string in one dimensional Array with lower and upper case is same/equivalent in Java?

Tags: java

I have one dimensional array, i want user to input a name to search. the array contain names of Leon, Helena, Chris, Piers, Jake, Sherry, and Ada. i want to use if statement, that if user type leon or LEON instead of Leon and other, it will be true. im using uppercase and lowercase too.

i used if statement combined with || attribute

```
public class CariNama {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] nama = {"Leon", "Helena", "Chris", "Piers", "Jake", "Sherry", "Ada"};
    String temp, tempchange, tempchange1;
    int i, proximator=0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert RE 6 Characters name : ");
    temp=keyboard.nextLine();
    tempchange=temp.toLowerCase();
    tempchange1=temp.toUpperCase();
    for(i=0;i<nama.length;i++){
        if(nama[i].equals(temp)||nama[i].equals(tempchange)||nama[i].equals(tempchange1)){
            proximator = 1;
        }
    }
    if(proximator==1){
        System.out.println("Character "+temp+" Found!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("There is no "+temp);
    }
    System.out.println(tempchange); //to make sure if tempchange is lowered
    System.out.println(tempchange1); //to make sure if tempchange1 is upper-ed
}
```

}

but when i type LEON or leon it still said there is no LEON or leon
if i type Leon then it said Character Leon Found, how do i fix this help

Comment: You should try `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, equalsIgnorecase method is the ideal solution here. Find the refactored code below.

```
public class CariNama {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] nama = {"Leon", "Helena", "Chris", "Piers", "Jake", "Sherry", "Ada"};
    String temp;
    int proximator=0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert RE 6 Characters name : ");
    temp=keyboard.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<nama.length;i++){
        if (nama[i].equalsIgnoreCase(temp)){
        proximator = 1;
        break;
        }
    }
    if(proximator==1){
        System.out.println("Character "+temp+" Found!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("There is no "+temp);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tempchange1 contains an all-uppercase variation; tempchange contains an all-lowercase version. Neither of these will match "Leon" which is what is in the array 'nama'.

`equalsIgnoreCase` is what you want.  Then you can just compare the input without making uppercase or lowercase variations of the input.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: don't use this solution, it's not general across languages like Turkish and Greek.

I understand your question as asking: how can I perform a case insensitive search on strings?

I would change the `if` statement in your loop to:

```
if(nama[i].toLowerCase().equals(temp.toLowerCase()) {
    proximator = 1;
}
```

What this does is only compare the lowercase equivalents of the input and search strings.

Comment: This is not generally correct. For example, it would not work for the Turkish I. Use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method (if you're interested, that handles the Turkish I (et al) by checking both to lower and to upper case).

Comment: As a technical matter, that does not always work. There are letters -- Greek sigma for example -- that have two lowercase versions, and therefore you can end up with lowercase-sigma not matching lowercase-sigma. You can't just use uppercase either, since the reverse case exists, though I can't recall an example off hand.  ```equalsIgnoreCase``` must cope with this.  (Edit: @AndyTurner and I came up with the same objection!)

Comment: And it's less efficient, because it creates a new string.